# Funnel Use GA4 - Event based

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to create a funnel using the custom events, but whenever I try and create the funnel in exploration no data is returned. I can see the numbers in events. I want to document the stages of a signup process, e.g. create account, step 2, step 3 etc. Why won't this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of giving a dumb answer, I'm going to assume you have not filled out all the "Variables" and "Tab settings" needed for a report to be generated. See the example below:

[image]

In order for a report to be generated, you need at least:

- One DIMENSION (1), or the data in the columns for your report
- One METRIC (2), or data in the rows
- One set of data for the ROW (3)
- One set of data for the COLUMN (4)
- A set of VALUES (5)
- And also check the start and end dates for the report (6).

Hope this helps.